# Can I point to specific address of array?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have got couple of question:

1) What does

```
ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = & ps_lst_tmp [1];
```

mean?

2) If I understand pointers correctly, then if I write at the end of the code

```
ps_lst_tmp++;
```

then pointer ps_lst_tmp would point to a next element and... Would ps_lst_nodes point also to the next element or not?

The whole code:

```
struct s_node_lnk_lst  /* structure used for list  */
{
    sMSC_NODE             *ps_node;       /* node */
    unsigned long int      uli_occurs;    /* occurences */ 
    struct s_node_lnk_lst *ps_greather;   /* greather neighbour in list */
} *ps_lst_nodes = NULL,*ps_lst_tmp;

ps_lst_nodes = (struct s_node_lnk_lst *) malloc 
               (sizeof (struct s_node_lnk_lst) * uli_nb_items);
ps_lst_tmp     = ps_lst_nodes;
ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = & ps_lst_tmp [1];
```

Thank you

Comment: Is that a typo? It should either say `greether` or `grateher`, depending on what kind of social community app you're making (Facebook vs Faceoff).

Comment: Hi. @opc007 If any answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = & ps_lst_tmp [1];
```

It means that `ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather` now points to the second element of `ps_lst_nodes`

It is the same as: `ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = ps_lst_tmp + 1`.

---

No it wouldn't. Changing the value of a variable itself, doesn't change any other variable.

However you can point to a variable with multiple pointers, and when the variable is modified all pointers will 'see' the change.
To do that in this case you need a pointer to a pointer:

```
 struct s_node_lnk_lst** p = &ps_lst_nodes;
```

`p` now point to `ps_lst_nodes` and if `ps_lst_nodes` is incremented that change can be seen using the pointer `p` by dereferencing it: `*p`

Answer (score 0):

`ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = & ps_lst_tmp [1]` is same to `ps_lst_tmp->ps_greather = ps_lst_tmp + 1`

`ptr + i` is equivalent to `&ptr[i]` and `ps_lst_tmp++` is same to `ps_lst_tmp = &ps_lst_tmp[1]`.

So `ps_lst_tmp++` will point to `ps_lst_nodes[1]`. At the same time `ps_lst_nodes` won't be changed